# Laravel: How to get counter value when inserting with UUID and Auto Increment

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

My models have both `id` and `counter` attributes.  The id is a UUID, and the counter is an integer which is auto-incremented by the database.

Both are unique however I rely on `id` as the primary key.  The `counter` is just a human-friendly name that I sometimes display to the user.

Immediately before an object is created a listener gives it a UUID.  This works fine.

When the record is saved, MySQL increments the counter field.  This works fine except that the copy of the object which I have in memory does not have the counter value.  I can reload the object to find out what its counter is, but that would require another database query.

Is there a way to find the value of the counter without a specific database query?  For example, is it returned as part of the response from the database when a record is created?

Comment: do mind sharing a code snippet of how are you doing, because ideally when you perform $object->save() or setting and saving attributes in any other way, the $object does have the exact values stored in the database against that record as eloquent returns you the stored object as per documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#inserts

Answer (score 0):

Few things:

1. Use `create(array $attributes)` and you'll get exactly what you want. For this having right, you have to ensure that `$fillable` array consists all attributes' names passed to create method.
2. You should use Observer on model instead of listener (most likely creating method).
3. Personal preference using Eloquent is that you should use `id` for id (increment field) and forget custom settings between models because by default it is what relations expect and so on

   ```
   public function secondModels()
   {
       return $this->hasMany(SecondModel::class);
   }
   ```

is pretty much no brainer. But for having this working best way would be (also following recommendations of [this guy](https://github.com/alexeymezenin/laravel-best-practices)) `FirstModel::id`, `SecondModel::id`, `SecondModel::first_model_id`; `first_models`, `second_models` as table names. Avoiding and/or skipping this kind of unification is lot of custom job afterward. I don't say it can't be done but it is lot of non-first-time-successful work done.

4. Also, if you want visitor to get something other than `id` field name, you can make computed field with accessor:

   ```
   /**
    * Get the user's counter.
    *
    * @return string
    */
   public function getCounterAttribute(): string
   {
       return (string)$this->id;
   }
   ```

Which you call then with `$user->counter`.

5. Also personal preference of mine is to have most possible descriptive variable names so uuid field of mine would be something like

   ```
   $table->uuid('uuid4');
   ```

This is some good and easy to make practice of Eloquent use.

Saying all this let me just to say that `create()` and `save()` will return created object from database while `insert()` shall not do it.

Comment: **2**. You should reference what you're talking about here. [reference](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent#events) **3**. This is wrong. Eloquent does not expect `id` it expects the primary key. [See here](https://github.com/illuminate/database/blob/master/Eloquent/Concerns/HasRelationships.php#L329-L331).

Comment: @LinusJuhlin **2** would require more explanation and I was afraid it would go more from initial question. I rationalized (text of) these practice of use as much as I could. Of course any additional question can be also adequately answered. **3** you are right if we are talking of variable *name* which is `$primaryKey`, or `$this->primaryKey` (depending on scope) but I am saying that it's **value** is expected to be `id` which is followed with bunch of code expectations (e.g. foreign key in child table for reference, avoiding nullable arguments in relationship methods etc.)